# How do you add all elements in a vector together? c++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm very new to coding and was just playing around with vectors however I cant seem to find out how to add all elements in a vector together when the amount of elements is user-defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int NoOfItems;
int i=1;
double Odds;
double Cost;
vector<double> CaseNumber;

int main()
{ 
    cout << "How many items in the case: ";
    cin >> NoOfItems;
    while (true) {    
        if (NoOfItems == 0) {
            break;
        } else { 
            cout << "Odds for item " << i <<endl;
            cin >> Odds;
            CaseNumber.push_back(Odds);
            NoOfItems = NoOfItems - 1;
            i = i + 1; 
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: `while (NoOfItems > 0) { ... }`

Comment: why are all of your variables global?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to spend some time cleaning up your code. There's some very questionable code conventions being used.

Anyways, to sum all of the elements of your vector:

```
double sum = 0;
for(size_t index = 0; index < CaseNumber.size(); index++) {
    sum += CaseNumber[index];
}
```

Or, in a way that's slightly more friendly to the semantics of C++:

```
double sum = 0;
for(double & d : CaseNumber) {
    sum += d;
}
```

Either will result in the variable `sum` containing the sum total of all elements in `CaseNumber`

Comment: That, or use `std::accumulate`.

Comment: @LouisDionne That too, although given that the user appears to be extremely new to C++ programming, I'd probably recommend this method instead to ensure they understand the underlying mechanics of what they're trying to do.

Comment: _@Xirema_ You should at least mention @Louis proposal in your question, because that would make your answer different from the most upvoted and accepted answer in the already proposed duplicate.